# MVC 5: Same PartialView object in different tabs - DataTables not rendering/populating

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC 5, so apologies if this is not a good question. I saw a lot of similar questions, not identical, and I have no solution.

I have an MVC 5 application with my main page (Index.cshtml) housing a Bootstrap tab menu. Each item is a partial view, all of which display correctly (for the most part). Two of the tabs (Plan Overview and Analytics) use the same tables for navigation, so this navigation sidebar references the same partial view.

When loading the application, the default tab selection is the Plan Overview. The two DataTable objects in question (planGrid and assetGrid) load and format correctly (I am changing the column widths and header text). When I select the Analytics tab, which also references the same partial view, I get unformatted headers and no data. The JS file which does this is not executing, even though its initial execution should load and populate this object.

I am sure I have a few things I'm off on here. Where do I start?

ETA: Code:

_MainLayout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - SNOWMAN v0.3</title>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/DataTables/datatables.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/SNOWMAN.js")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</head>
<body>

@RenderBody()
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "SNOWMAN Launch"; 
}

<div class="titleBar">
<b>SNOWMAN</b>
</div>
<div class="titleBarBorder"> </div>
<div class="tabMenu">
<ul id="tabStrip" class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#_PlanOverviewTab" role="tab" data-toggle="pill">Plan Overview</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#_AnalyticsTab" role="tab" data-toggle="pill">Analytics</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#_HelpTab" role="tab" data-toggle="pill">Help</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content clearfix">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="_PlanOverviewTab">@Html.Partial("_PlanOverviewTab")</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="_AnalyticsTab">@Html.Partial("_AnalyticsTab")</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="_HelpTab">@Html.Partial("_HelpTab")</div>
</div>
```

```
@section scripts {
<script>
   $('#tabStrip a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var tabID = $(this).attr("href").substr(1);
        $(".tab-pane").each(function () {
            $(this).empty();
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "/@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]/" + tabID,
            cache: false,
            type: "get",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#" + tabID).html(result);
            }
        })
        $(this).tab('show')
    });
</script>
}
```

_PlanOverViewTab.cshtml

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "_PlanOverviewTab";
}

<div class="subContainer">

<div class="planSidebar">
    @Html.Partial("_PlanSidebar")
</div>

<div class="planDetails">

</div>
```

_PlanSidebar.cshtml

```
<table id="planGrid" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Plan_ID</th>
            <th>Plan_Description</th>
            <th>Asset_IDs</th>
            <th>Assets</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<table id="assetGrid" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Asset_ID</th>
            <th>Asset</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: show us your code in your question then we can help you. but from your description "js does not execute" means your partial view is rendering the js in the middle of your <body> tag (or something)

Comment: I think the issue is because duplicate datatable id, you have 2 instances with the same id, it doesn't work this way, I suggest you start by creating 2 different partial views, and assign unique ids for the tables

Comment: @Munzer I have actually already tried this. Using separate controls for the Analytics tab, the controls display and populate with data, but the formatting never occurs. The column names display with underscores and the column widths are not set. That is to say it goes one step further, but still incorrect

Comment: I cannot read the url routes - try downloading fiddler and check your http ajax get request to see if the tabId is being passed into your method correctly. otherwise you will have to setup a route with the id parameter called "tabId".